# formControlName causing radio button selection to not work

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, radio-button

I have an odd behaviour in my ionic form. Whenever I add formControlName to the radio button div and try selecting each value by clicking on them, I can see the DOM changing when I inspect the element, but visually, nothing happens i.e. the dot doesn't move to the value I clicked on.

When I delete formControlName from the element, the radio button control works as normal.

It worked fine when I was using ngmodel, but when Angular forced me to use formControlName instead, the radio button started doing this odd behaviour and I haven't been able to get it working properly.

What I can't figure out is what I'm missing or doing wrong. Do I have to use a different form layout to be able to successfully use formControlName?

The html is:

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm">
  <ion-label stacked>Choose an option:</ion-label>
  <div id="scope" radio-group formControlName="scope" class="radio-group--inline" [class.invalid]="!loginForm.controls.scope.valid && (loginForm.controls.scope.dirty || submitAttempt)">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-radio checked="true" value="value1" class="radio radio-inline">Value1</ion-radio>
        <ion-label>Value 1</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-radio value="value2" class="radio radio-inline">Value2</ion-radio>
      <ion-label>Value 2</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </div>
</form>
```

The .ts file is:

```
constructor() {
  this.loginForm = formBuilder.group({
    scope: this.scope,
  });
}
```

Comment: You have `formControlName="scope"` on a `div`?

Comment: @AlphaBeta its working please check link https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-9d6jzb

Comment: @Abhishek, thanks for the link. Yes I see it works and I've tried deleting all the other controls and text from my form to match what you have there, but the radio controls still only work when I delete formControlName. Is there any other way to do Angular forms without using formControlName?

Comment: @MaihanNijat, I've tried changing the div to an ion-list, but it makes no difference.

Comment: @AlphaBeta have you missed any module?  because if code is running on the link its also run in your local environment.